# How to send a message from puppeteer to a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I wrote a chrome extension that recording a screen by using chrome.tabCapture API. I want to be able to start and stop recording by using puppeteer.

Starting a recording was an easy part because I need to start it from the beginning - I'm just sending a message from the content script:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "START_CAPTURING"}, function(response) {});
}, 100);
```

Now, I can't figure out how can I send a message from puppeteer to the background script to stop the capturing.
I tried to add a button to the page and waiting for the click event inside the content script:

```
var button = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "STOP_CAPTURING"}, function(response) {});
  }, false);
```

It works. The problem with this approach is that even if I'm the owner of the content and able to add an additional element just for sake of 
recording, it seems to me not an elegant solution.

I would expect to be able to send messages from puppeteer to extensions or calling functions declared in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/externally_connectable/) in your manifest, and then `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` will become available to the specified host.

```json
{
  "name": "My externally connectable extension",
  "externally_connectable": {
    // If this field is not specified, no webpages can connect.
    // You cannot specify "all URLs"
    "matches": [
      "*://*.example.com/*",
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

On the puppeteer side, I assume it would look like:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('your extension id', { action: "STOP_CAPTURING"})
});
```

The message will be **received by your background worker.**